# Unbind events from Backbone Js View, with out effecting the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

There is a backbone view and it has some events for particular classes. let's say html will be like this.

```
<div class=""some1">
  <a href="#" class="inner1"> Loaction 1 </a>
  <a href="#" class="inner2"> Loaction 2 </a>
  <a href="#" class="inner3"> Loaction 3 </a>
   // All possible hierarchy goes here , like combination of div , a, span 
   //   and every tag has class
   // for classes there will be backbone view

   <input class="inputclass" type="text"> // input submission

</div>
```

and lets say backbone view will be

```
//sampleView.js

 template: '_SampleHtml',
 events: {
        "click .inner1": "clickinner1",
        "click .inner2": "clickinner2",
        "click .inner3": "clickinner3",
        "click .inner4": "clickinner4",
        ...
        ....
        ......
        "click .inputclass": "inpputclass",
    },
    clickinner1: function() {
    //do something
    },

    clickinner2: function() {
    //do something
    },

    clickinner3: function() {
    //do something
    },

    clickinner4: function() {
    //do something
    }

    inpputclass: function() {
    // if input is having one particular condition 
    // i want to remove all the events i.e only 'onclick ' should not work on view, 
     //means even if you click 'Loaction 1 ' , respective event should not occur 
    // and contents should be present on DOM
    }
```

I tried "***unbind()***","***off"***,"***stopListening()***","***delegate events*** in Backbone". nothing has worked for my criteria.
when I used delegates, contents are removing from DOM.
Is there any method to remove all events which comes under particular div. like "some1"?

P.S: I am attaching an image, where I occurred this problem. Please follow to get exact idea.[image]

Comment: there is no `afterrender` function in backbone... like i said earlier, `undelegateEvents` removes events and does not remove view from DOM, if that is happening it has to do with the code inside your project, which we can't see and hence we can't solve your problem unless you share a [mcve]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`undelegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents) to remove all event listeners from the view

Comment: Delegateevents removes view from DOM... for my html, if I use delegates, it will show empty page since no DOM is present.

Comment: @Kvs it doesn't. It just removes the events. Probably the problem with your code is something else. Can you show an example?

Comment: It's not possible to write code here, so I am attaching Image to my question as well now with a brief explanation. plz follow @T J